# jquery.sumoselect not showing checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I have the following code, which fetches data dynamically and shoves it into a [sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/).

```
<select id="geoSel_location_2">



</select>


<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var returnSelect = jQuery('#geoSel_location_2'); 

        returnSelect.SumoSelect({placeholder: 'All Suburbs'});

        jQuery.getJSON("/cfcs/system.cfc?method=getSelectsRelated&returnformat=json&queryformat=column",{"type":"location","id":4,"index":2},function(res,code) {
            if(res.ROWCOUNT > 0){
                for(i=0; i<res.ROWCOUNT; i++){
                    var val = res.DATA.OPTION_VALUE[i];
                    var text = res.DATA.OPTION_TEXT[i];
                    returnSelect[0].sumo.add(val,text);
                };
            };
        });

    })

</script>
```

The options load beautifully, but the multi-select checkboxes are not showing next to each option. I thought they showed by default.

The jsfiddle is a simplified version of the above.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5ta7az0w/)

Comment: Can you replicate this in `Jsfiddle`?

Answer (score 2):

OK, duh, the solution is to add "multiple="multiple", i.e.

```
<select "multiple="multiple" id="geoSel_location_2">
    <option value="1">Auckland</option>
    <option value="2">Wellington</option>
    <option value="3">Christchurch</option>
    <option value="4">Dunedin</option>
</select>
```